# How to increase the maxReceivedMessageSize calling a WCF from ssrs report?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm calling a WCF to obtain database information from a SSRS report, it works retrieving small amounts of data, but with bigger queries, it throws an exception

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Normally you can configure the `maxReceivedMessageSize` property at the client's configuration file, but I can't find where to configure this property in the report.

Comment: You don't change that setting in the report, you change it in the configuration on the client AND the server (WCF).

Comment: My client is the report, I have a Datasource that connect the report and the WCF via XML with a query.

Comment: Okay, good to know. I am interested in what you end up having to do with this now.

Answer (score 0):

take look at this file:

```
<Installation directory> \Reporting Services \ReportServer\RSReportServer.config
```

or

```
<Installation directory> \Reporting Services \ReportServer\Web.config
```